# How to search for the inclusion of a specific library on GitHub

Tags: github, search

I have a question about how to search on GitHub.

For example, if I want to find repositories that are using "Nuxt3" and "Vuetify3," how should I search for them?

I tried searching with a query like "nuxt": "^3" "vuetify": "^3," but as shown in the image below, it includes results for Vuetify 2.x and Nuxt 3.x.

[image]

Is there a way to search specifically for repositories that are using only Nuxt and Vuetify version 3.x, so that I can filter out results for other versions like Vuetify 2.x and Nuxt 3.x?

Answer (score 0):

I resolved it by enclosing the entire thing in double quotes and escaping the double quotes with a backslash.

`"\"nuxt\": \"^3" "\"vuetify\": \"^3"`